# Unity2D problems with raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im doing a match-3 game, and to break the candies I used Raycast, but when I try to show how many candies had the player broken, it shows one less than expected.

```
private List<GameObject> FindMatch(Vector2 direction)
    {
        List<GameObject> matchingCandies = new List<GameObject>();
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, direction);
        while(hit.collider != null && hit.collider.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite == spriteRenderer.sprite) {
            matchingCandies.Add(hit.collider.gameObject);
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(hit.collider.transform.position, direction);
        }

        return matchingCandies;
    }

    private bool ClearMatch(Vector2[] directions)
    {
        List<GameObject> matchingCandies = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach(Vector2 direction in directions) {
            matchingCandies.AddRange(FindMatch(direction));
        }
        if(matchingCandies.Count >= BoardManager.MinCandiesToMatch) {
            foreach(GameObject candy in matchingCandies){
                goalManager.CompareGoals(candy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.ToString());
                goalManager.UpdateGoals();
    }
```

```
public class BlankGoal
{
    public int numberNeeded;
    public int numberCollected;
}

public class GoalManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BlankGoal[] levelGoals;

public void UpdateGoals()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < levelGoals.Length; i++)
        {
            currentGoals[i].thisText.text = "" + levelGoals[i].numberCollected + "/" + levelGoals[i].numberNeeded;
            if(levelGoals[i].numberCollected >= levelGoals[i].numberNeeded)
            {
                goalsCompleted++;
                currentGoals[i].thisText.text = "" + levelGoals[i].numberNeeded + "/" + levelGoals[i].numberNeeded;
            }
        }
    }

    public void CompareGoals(string goalToCompare)
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < levelGoals.Length; i++)
        {
            if(goalToCompare == levelGoals[i].matchValue)
            {
                levelGoals[i].numberCollected++;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I break 3 candies, the numberCollected is 2, if I break 4 is 3, and so on

Comment: why do you do repeating raycasts when you can do the 1 and  check what you hit? in one go? have you used gyzmos to check where you're actually raycasting from?

Comment: Start by putting a Debug.Log() before the conditional that sets `numberCollected++;` and see when it doesn't trigger, and why.

Comment: Thanks, I have just fixed it